# inserting doctrine form data to database in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL database.

Here is my form, in action.class.php `$this->formTodo = new LpTodoGeneralForm();`

and the LpTodoGeneralForm.class.php is:

```
<?php

class LpTodoGeneralForm extends BaseFormDoctrine{
    public function configure(){      
        $this->widgetSchema['deadline_date'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-text small datepicker', 'readonly' => 'readonly'));
        $this->widgetSchema['firm_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-text datepicker'));
        $this->validatorSchema['todo_by'] = new sfValidatorPass(array('required' => true));
        $this->widgetSchema['todo_by'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-text small datepicker', 'readonly' => 'readonly'));
    }

    public function setup(){
        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'done'              => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
            'deadline'          => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
            'deadline_date'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'firm_name'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'description'       => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),
            'todo_by'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
        ));

        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('todo[%s]');
        $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
        $this->setupInheritance();

        parent::setup();
    }

    public function getModelName(){
        return 'Todo';
    }  
}
```

While submitting the form I am getting the post data in action.class.php.
My challenge is how to insert this data into the database.

Comment: Please, first read this http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/11-Doctrine-Integration and other chapters http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en

Comment: thanks, i have gone through that. Created the schema and generated module for that. But now i am facing another porblem, getting error 
Unexpected extra form field named "deadline_date".

Comment: Every form field has to have a corresponding validator pair so add a validator for `deadline_date`.

Comment: please go through this: i have made another question regarding it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744485/unexpected-extra-form-field-validation-error-while-submitting-in-symfony-1?noredirect=1#comment47710532_29744485

Answer (score 0):

the link is dead for rb vishnu's last comment.

and 1ed is correct.

The form will insert the data once the validator for deadline_date is created.

the "extra form field" is a pretty common issue in symfony 1.4 forms.